# Bootstrap 3 grid 3 column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to deploy my checkbox in 3 column in bootstrap 3

example:

chk1  chk2  chk3

chk4  chk5  chk6

chk7  chk8  chk9

Here is my try :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <hr class="hr">
<h3>Izaberi ostale opcije:</h3>


<input type="checkbox" id='Kabinet'>  <label for="check1">Kabinet</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Monitor'>  <label for="check1">Monitor</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Bravice'>  <label for="check1">Bravice</label>



<input type="checkbox" id='Pojacalo'>  <label for="check1">Pojacalo</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Coin usta'>  <label for="check1">Coin usta</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Bar kod'>  <label for="check1">Bar kod</label>


<input type="checkbox" id='Toper'>  <label for="check1">Toper</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Monitor + Touch'>  <label for="check1">Monitor+Touch</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Brojaci'>  <label for="check1">Brojaci</label>


    </div>
```

i try it to put class=" col-md-6" and other but it don't work.. I thinking of using css for that but then i don't need bootstrap.. and it will not be responsive. Do you have some idea. I'am new to bootstrap. Do I need new rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy, Use 3 div's, if you want in 3 columns otherwise if you want in rows as stated in your eg. replace below class to `col-md-12` :-

```
<div class="row">

    <hr class="hr">
<h3>Izaberi ostale opcije:</h3>
<div class="col-md-4">    

<input type="checkbox" id='Kabinet'>  <label for="check1">Kabinet</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Monitor'>  <label for="check1">Monitor</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Bravice'>  <label for="check1">Bravice</label>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
<input type="checkbox" id='Pojacalo'>  <label for="check1">Pojacalo</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Coin usta'>  <label for="check1">Coin usta</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Bar kod'>  <label for="check1">Bar kod</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="checkbox" id='Toper'>  <label for="check1">Toper</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Monitor + Touch'>  <label for="check1">Monitor+Touch</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='Brojaci'>  <label for="check1">Brojaci</label>   

    </div>
```